# Changing pos while changing node labels in grid_2d_graph networkx

Tags: python, graph, grid, networkx

I'm changing the labels of nodes in grid_2d_graph using `nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers` and I want nodes to stay at the same places they were before changing the labels. Obviously, I have to transform `pos` the same way I converted node labels before and give new `pos` as an argument to `nx.draw()`. However, I can't understand how to do this easily. Can you help me?

Here's my code

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = 0
end = 7

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(3,3)
pos = dict(zip(G,G)) # dictionary of node names->positions
G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G, ordering = 'sorted')

node_colors = ["lightblue" if n == start or n == end else "white" for n in G.nodes()]
edge_colors = ["blue" if n == (1, 2) else "gray" for n in G.edges()]
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True,  edge_color = edge_colors, node_color = node_colors, width = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the positions as node attributes and they will persist through the relabeling.  Use `networkx.set_node_attributes()` and `networkx.get_node_attributes()` as follows

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = 0
end = 7

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(3,3)
pos = dict(zip(G,G)) # dictionary of node names->positions
nx.set_node_attributes(G,'pos',pos)
G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G, ordering = 'sorted',
                                       label_attribute = 'origin' )

node_colors = ["lightblue" if n == start or n == end else "white" for n in G.nodes()]
edge_colors = ["blue" if n == (1, 2) else "gray" for n in G.edges()]
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True,  edge_color = edge_colors, node_color = node_colors, width = 3)
```

I also set the `label_attribute` keyword to 'origin' which records the original node names as the attribute 'origin'.  So you can check the result

```
>>> list(G.nodes(data=True))
[(0, {'origin': (0, 0), 'pos': (0, 0)}),
 (1, {'origin': (0, 1), 'pos': (0, 1)}),
 (2, {'origin': (0, 2), 'pos': (0, 2)}),
 (3, {'origin': (1, 0), 'pos': (1, 0)}),
 (4, {'origin': (1, 1), 'pos': (1, 1)}),
 (5, {'origin': (1, 2), 'pos': (1, 2)}),
 (6, {'origin': (2, 0), 'pos': (2, 0)}),
 (7, {'origin': (2, 1), 'pos': (2, 1)}),
 (8, {'origin': (2, 2), 'pos': (2, 2)})]
```